# why set solutions u equals to eigenvectors multiply v

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the following:

> In the equation $\frac{d \mathbf u}{dt} = A \mathbf u$, the matrix $A$ couples the pure solutions. We set $\mathbf u = S \mathbf v$, where $S$ is the matrix of eigenvectors of $A$, to get:
> $$
> S \frac{d \mathbf v}{dt} = A S\mathbf v
> $$
> or:
> $$
> \frac{d \mathbf v}{dt} = S^{-1}A S\mathbf v = \Lambda \mathbf v.
> $$
> This diagonalizes the system: $\frac{dv_i}{dt} = \lambda_iv_i$. The general solution is then:
> \begin{align}
> &\mathbf v(t) &= \qquad &e^{\Lambda t} \mathbf v(0), \quad \text{and}\\
> &\mathbf u(t) &= \qquad &Se^{\Lambda t} S^{-1} \mathbf v(0) = e^{At} \mathbf u(0).
> \end{align}

[the question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkRGZ.png)

Why do we able to set $\mathbf u = S \mathbf v$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @DanielClarke Please explain your question further. The reason that we defined $\mathbf v$ by setting $\mathbf u = S \mathbf v$ is *in order to diagonalize the system and obtain a solution*. However, I expect that you already know this because this is exactly what is written in the excerpt that you included. So, if what you're looking for is not the answer to this question, then what question are you really trying to ask?

Comment: @DanielClarke It would be useful if, for instance, you could point to specific parts of the excerpt that you don't understand.

Comment: @DanielClarke As an analogy: if I were explaining how to "complete the square", I might show the following steps:
$$
x^2 - 4x = \\
(x^2 - 4x + 4) - 4 =\\
(x - 2)^2 - 4.
$$
If someone asked "why did you add and subtract $4$", then I would say "in order to complete the square", or "in order to obtain a perfect square for the next step", but this doesn't seem like an enlightening answer. The question that you are asking is similar.

Comment: @BenGrossmann sorry sire i didn't describe my question explicitly,by that i mean why is u able to equal Sv, u just an unknown vector, why is it related to eigenvector and this v which i don't know what it represents for

Comment: @saulspatz thank you sir for helping me formatting my question

Comment: @DanielClarke $\mathbf v = S \mathbf u$ is a useful substitution. Here is another analogy: suppose I have the equation
$$
e^{2x} - 4e^{x} + 3 = 0.
$$
In order to solve this, I could make the *substitution* $y = e^{x}$ to rewrite this as
$$
y^2 - 4y + 3 = 0 \implies (y - 3)(y-1) = 0 \implies y = 1,3 
$$
So, we have $e^x = 1,e^x = 3 \implies x = \ln(1) = 0, x = \ln(3)$.

Comment: @saulspatz I can understand your example, but y of your example represents nothing, and the 'S' of Sv means eigenvector matrix, I really confused about here, and are the 'v' and 'u' the same thing? they both are unknown vectors?

Comment: I don't think you meant to address that last comment to me.

Comment: @saulspatz yeh sorry,,,,XD

Comment: @BenGrossmann  I can understand your example, but y of your example represents nothing, and the 'S' of Sv means eigenvector matrix, I really confused about here, and are the 'v' and 'u' the same thing? they both are unknown vectors?

Comment: Daniel, @BenGrossmann is just trying to show you some uses (reasons for) substitution. When you substitute, you can substitute anything you like if it helps you get additional insight into the problem. Like in Ben's case, substituting $y=e^x$ reduced the problem to a easily solvable quadratic equation, which meakes finding the desired $x$ easy. In your case, using $\mathbb{u} = S\mathbb{v}$ helps transform the problem into a much easier one, and once you know what $\mathbb{v}$ is, it becomes easy to find the $\mathbb{u}$ that you really seek.

Comment: @DanielClarke In the same way that $x$ is not the same as $y$ in my example, $\mathbf u$ is not the same as $\mathbf v$.

Comment: @DanielClarke Maybe this would help: because $S$ is invertible, saying "we set $\mathbf u = S \mathbf v$" is the same thing as saying "we set $\mathbf v = S^{-1} \mathbf u$".

Comment: @BenGrossmann you guys make me some sense, it's that right that set  u=Sv just like Ax=b, and v just some unknown vector, solve v first then go back to my target u

Comment: @gt6989b you guys make me some sense, it's that right that set u=Sv just like Ax=b, and v just some unknown vector, solve v first then go back to my target u

Comment: @DanielClarke indeed, that's exactly what is happening